# How to Delay SMS Messages in Twilio Studio?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to use Twilio Studio to send multiple SMS messages to a person triggered from the Rest API.

However, I need there to be a delay of 24 hours between the messages.

How do I go about adding this? I've tried following the "Add A Delay" Twilio article for creating a function but the code doesn't seem to be working properly and all my messages get sent at the same time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Studio doesn’t have native scheduling functionality but the /Messages resource does. You can schedule messages out to 7 days in advanced.

Reference this blog post and documentation for more details.

Message Scheduling is Now in Public Beta
https://www.twilio.com/blog/message-scheduling-public-beta

Can I schedule Twilio messages to be sent at a future time or date?
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/4406956913307-Can-I-schedule-Twilio-messages-to-be-sent-at-a-future-time-or-date-

Schedule a Message resource
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#schedule-a-message-resource

Comment: Is there no way to get a delay function to run in Studio though? That's where I need it to work at...

Comment: There isn't. Maybe you can use an external scheduler like Google Apps Script that can trigger a Studio Execution at some point in the future.

Google Apps Script
https://script.google.com/home/start

Time Based Triggers
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BYhGGPQlyA

Exact Time Triggers
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vob6Qy01-_Y&feature=youtu.be

Google App Script
Time-driven-triggers
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers